# Android: обновить title по таймеру

Tags: java, android

Каким образом можно обновлять заголовок ActionBar по таймеру? нужно выводить туда произвольные числа через определённый интервал.
Пробую так:

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
           couter ++
           setTitle(String.valueof(counter));
      }
}, 0, 100);
```

Показывает ошибку:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        counter ++;
                        setTitle(String.valueof(counter));
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Тут же все и так ясно

```
 Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views
```

Тоесть вы пытаетесь не в оригинальном потоке запустить setTitle.

Используйте `runOnUiThread`
Или поулчите `Handler` активити где лежит `View` к которому принадлежит метод `setTitle`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось